# Custom NSURLProtocol to show/hide NetworkActivityIndicator

Tags: objective-c, swift, alamofire

I'm working with Alamofire. Following up on Mattt's comment in one of the [closed issues](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/185) on GitHub, I attempted a `NSURLProtocol`-based mechanism to set the `UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible` flag.

However, after registering my custom protocol with Alamofire's underlying `NSURLSessionConfiguration` I got stuck pretty quickly since Alamofire doesn't expose much of its `SessionDelegate` class.

Is there a simple way to notify the custom `NSURLProtocol` the request has completed without reproducing much of the already existing implementation of Alamofire inside my `NSURLProtocol`?

Answer (score 0):

A different way of doing it (not implementing NSURLProtocol-way) would be creating an API which would have an **executeRequest** method:

```
func executeRequest(method: Alamofire.Method, url: NSURL, parameters: [String: String]?, headers: [String : String]?) {
        // Show activity indicator on status bar
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        let request = manager.request(method, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
            .responseJSON {
                response in
                ...

                // Hide activity indicator on status bar
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }
    }
```

Of course, all your requests would have to be executed using the newly created API.

Comment: But this breaks as soon as you have two concurrent requests, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. Having two requests, if one of them finishes earlier, the activity indicator will hide before the second request finishes too. But this can be easily fixed. You can keep count of active requests, and hide the activity indicator only when active requests count is 0.